# Fetching Remote Encryption Key for MariaDB

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I've set up encryption at rest for MariaDB but I can't seem to get my key fetching service to fetch the key.

I have the following fetch script and a systemd service set up.

```
# Fetch the encryption file for MariaDB, restart service, then remove file
/usr/bin/wget -P /etc/mysql https://example.com/my_maria_key.key 
/bin/systemctl restart mysql
sleep 10
rm /etc/mysql/my_maria_key.key
touch /tmp/mariadb.started
exit 0
```

And my systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I made sure I enabled the service and I can run the service using:

```
sudo service fetch_key restart
```

But it doesn't fetch the key.

What have I done wrong?

> ADDING .CNF FOR REFERENCE

```
[mysqld]
plugin_load_add=file_key_management
file_key_management = ON
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/secretkeyname.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm=aes_cbc
encrypt_binlog = 1
innodb_encrypt_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
aria_encrypt_tables = ON
encrypt_tmp_disk_tables = ON
innodb_encryption_threads = 8
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 0 # Do not rotate key
```

> ADDING VARIOUS KEY GENERATION RESULTS

```
when using wget via sudo in the terminal: 
644 -rw-r--r-- root root 620 mysecretkey.enc

letting the service download the key:
660 -rw-rw---- root root 620 mysecretkey.enc

generating the key with openssl:
644 -rw-r--r-- root root 336 mysecretkey.enc
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making it its own server, extend the mariadb service:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
```

create a file `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/prefetch.conf` with contents

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/wget -P /etc/mysql https://example.com/my_maria_key.key
ExecStartPost={something to ensure the key is loaded - mysql -e '...' } 
ExecStartPost=rm my_maria_key.key
```

I don't know if this will deleting the key too early. Consider including `journalctl -u mariadb.service -n 50` in your question.

Comment: I gave this a try and the ExecStartPre service doesn't ever get run that I can see here from the mariadb status. Its too long to post here in a comment.

Comment: OK I had the name of the file wrong, .cnf instead of .conf. So now the ExecStartPre runs and saves the key to the correct directory, but mysql will not start. Do you know what the permissions of that key file should be? I can't imagine why it would encrypt my tables on first run, then not let the server start once it's removed and redownloaded.

Comment: Adding my encrypt.cnf to my original question.

Comment: Yes I think the permissions are the issue. When a make the key using openssl the file has permissions of 644 but when I import it via the service it has a permission of 660. I tried adding a new pre command `ExecStartPre={chmod 644 /etc/mysql/mysecretkey.enc}` but it had no effect. How do I change the file permission after the key downloads?

Comment: `PermissionsStartOnly=true` means its doing pre/post as root. You can enter multiple `ExecStartPre/Post`

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means. How does this change the file permissions? Is that line correct in my comment, the command goes inside `{}`?It also looks like my file size is different when it's downloaded, compared to when the key is generated on the server. Perhaps you can post a full answer that shows the whole service?

Comment: Added differences in key size and permissions with various generations to question

Comment: mariadb is running as the `mysql` user which significantly affects permissions.